# Docker log-driver blocking mode

Tags: docker

When log driver is set to blocking mode, docker says it can block the application due to back pressure. Is there some metrics/stats available that tells me how often is my application back pressuring?

I've noticed that we are using mode=blocking in production and would like to know its impact